# How to detach instead of terminate a GNU Screen session inside xterm when pressing C-c?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, xterm

On X startup the following is ran automatically:

xterm -e screen -rS app1

This opens up an xterm session and attaches the screen of app1, which was already running in a detached state.

**What I'd like to achieve is the ability to close the xterm window, using `ctrl-c`, without terminating the GNU screen session.** The exhibited behavior when pressing `ctrl-c` is that app1 and the screen session terminates.

I was reading on the *autodetach* feature but so far and I haven't been successful and I don't know if this is what I need.

I'm running KDE with SLES 11.3.

Comment: Have you tried the screen detach commands, such as Ctrl-A d ?

Comment: Yes I suspect this would work, except the users of the system would not know of it, and would probably resort to ctrl-c to close the window.

Answer (score 0):

"Closing an xterm window" is not typically done with `Ctrl-C`.  What's probably happening is that the application is catching it (SIGINT) and exiting gracefully, leaving the screen session, leading to closing the terminal (window).

Your goal seems to be that `Ctrl-C` should be handled by screen to detach the application, which can be done by the screen mapping:

```
bindkey "\003" detach
```

You can issue this to test with `Ctrl-A :` then entering the above.  The syntax is the same for a custom .screenrc, but don't put it in there for any user, noone will be able to break out of any program inside that screen!  If you have the above, and an `autodetach on` in a `.my.screenrc` file, then you can invoke the original with `screen -c .my.screenrc`, then start the application inside.

I repeat, be aware that now `screen` is instructed to catch the interruption, no program started in this screen, not even programs started by your application can be stopped if they misbehave/hang, just from another terminal.

The `autodetach` option will take care of closing the window normally from your window manager.

Comment: wow! exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!